# Tree Traversal - DFS

Tags: haskell

I need to implement a DFS traversal on a Tree with a maximum depth ( so for example if the depth is 0 then you only show the root ).

successors node will return a list of (Int,Tree) where Tree is basically the "s" in my Node s a

```
limitedDfsRec :: (ProblemState s a, Ord s, Ord a) => [Node s a] -> Int -> S.Set (Node s a)-> [Node s a] -> [Node s a]
limitedDfsRec [] _ _ result = reverse result
limitedDfsRec (node:coada) max_depth visited result | adancime node > max_depth = limitedDfsRec coada max_depth visited result
                                                    | S.member node visited = limitedDfsRec coada max_depth visited result
                                                    | otherwise =
                                                    let succesori = [(Nod copil (Just actiune_copil) (Just $ stare node) ((adancime node) + 1) []) | (actiune_copil,copil) <- successors (stare node)]
                                                    in limitedDfsRec (succesori ++ coada) max_depth (S.insert node visited) (node : result)
```

You start from a node,if it's depth is greater than the maximum depth allowed you go to next element in the list (coada).
If the element is already visited then you go to the next element in the list.
Else,you get all the children (succesori) and put them in the list (coada),you add the element to the visited and to the final result.
That function is used toghether with this one :

```
instance ProblemState Tree Int where
    successors (Tree n)
        | n == 2    = [(1, Tree 4), (2, Tree 6)]  -- 4 instead of 5 => cycle
        | otherwise = [(1, Tree $ 2 * n + 1), (2, Tree $ 2 * n + 2)]

    isGoal (Tree n) = n == 13
```

Which generates the children. Well,the problem is that the function above still visits nodes even if they are in the visited set and I don't understand why.

So,for example, starting from Tree 0 with a maximum depth of 2 you should get [0,1,3,4,2,6] but my function gets [0,1,3,4,2,4,6] because when it gets to 2 it puts 4 and 6 in the list but when it gets to 4 it sees that 4 was not visited yet and puts it in the output (result).
I want to see the problem with THIS code,not other ways it works because I need to use this on more than 2 children.

Comment: In the future please share your whole code, because the lack of definitions makes your question harder to understand.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I can't really,this is a piece of code from a homework,if I share it people might find this and copy my code

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0):

You're keeping whole nodes in the `visited` set

```
| S.member node visited = ...
        -- ^ Node s a
```

So you can have multiple nodes labeled by 4 but with different extra information.
You probably only want a `visited :: S.Set s`.